# HIbernate - Isolation - Insert Record

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions, locking

Use Case

Need to store Coupons applied by Customer while purchasing an product.

Table structure as below.

ID | USERREF | COUPONCODE | DATE

1. Single User - Single Usage Coupon
2. Single User - Multiple Usage Coupon
3. Multi User - Single Coupon
4. Multi User - Multiple Coupon

I need to Insert new record for User and used coupon code, table can have multiple entries as per above requirements.

For use case, Single User - Single Usage Coupon, i can land up in trouble. Same  user can apply through 2 different modes.
One is i use synchronized block somewhere while R/W operations or i use table lock on above table when i read data actually.

Same goes for others, single user - multiple usage, can return multiple rows, and i can limit to max 3 times usages for user for same coupon.

So i need help if hibernate does provides or can i create constraint dynamically based on my use case.

Comment: I see many possible questions in your database design itself, and I think you should start there before bringing Hibernate into the picture.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually i want to make it like that, dynamic and one table for all usages, but whatever you want to suggest, maybe you can mention here.